# Salt Passwords do not match

Tags: php

Code on my register page:

```
 $p_salt = rand_string(20);
 $site_salt="subinsblogsalt"; /*Common Salt used for password storing on site.*/
 $salted_hash = hash('sha256', $password.$site_salt.$p_salt);
```

I then insert the salt in to the database, along with the salted passwords, but when I do it on my login page:

```
if(isset($_POST) && $email!='' && $password!=''){
 $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,psalt FROM user WHERE email='".$email."'");
 $sql->execute(array($email));
 while($r=$sql->fetch()){
  $p=$r['password'];
  $p_salt=$r['psalt'];
  $id=$r['id'];
 }
 $site_salt="subinsblogsalt";/*Common Salt used for password storing on site. You can't change it. If you want to change it, change it when you register a user.*/
 $salted_hash = hash('sha256', $password.$site_salt.$p_salt);
```

But they don't match at all, I echoed the salted hash to compare it to the one in the database but they're different.

Comment: Mind posting both results along with the input?

Comment: "Common Salt used for password storing on site" terrible practice may as well not salt it at all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Comment: @Dagon actually he is salting it with a random salt per user as well, if you read his code...

Comment: @jeromeudee What about the salt?  Did you compare the salt you're getting out with the salt you're storing, to ensure something hasn't gone awry there? Edit: also you should include the code you're using to store the data, in case there's an error there.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating and storing the password with:

```
$salted_hash = hash('sha256', $password.$site_salt.$p_salt);
```

But when you recover the password from your table you are encrypting to compare the password that is already encripted.

When you compare the passwords use `$p_salt`.